# How to use map created from MyMap into our application?

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a custom map into MyMap link on google map for creating our own map with adding various placemark points &/or lines.

see http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF&msa=0&msid=
113225627012396411583.000478b8658fde4ac307b

Can I use the url getting from crated map into our application to show it programmatically with adding some points through application with javascript instead of using following url:
    http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAcl

Regards,
Girish

Comment: Can I use the url in our application to sow map with adding other map extra map points/map content?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is go to the MyMap and grab the URL from the "View in Google Earth" link on the bar at the top of the map.

Then you can use that URL in a GGeoXml call in the Google Maps API.

Another thing you can do is go to the MyMAp and click the "Link" link on the bar at the top of the map. If you feel like it, use the "Customize and preview embedded map" option. Then grab the displayed HTML and paste it into your website.

In both those cases the data is dynamic. Future changes to the MyMap will be reflected on your website, after a few hours delay due to caching on the Google server.

If you want more control, then you'd need to consider third party extensions to the Google Maps API, such as EGeoXml, GeoXml or GeoXml3. In which case the data would normally be static and not reflect future changes to the MyMap, but you could write your own server-side code to refresh it.